# How to optimize duplicate search query

Tags: mysql

I have a table with about 400k records in it that I need to dedupe. I'm not deleting the records -- I need to identify the potential duplicates and return them for further analysis. The table has four columns: id, first_name, last_name, postal_code -- I'm matching on first_name, last_name, and postal_code. The id column is a primary key and the other three columns have indexes. My query is:

```
SELECT t1.id id1, t2.id id2, 3 weight
FROM dupe_table t1
JOIN dupe_table t2
  ON t1.first_name = t2.first_name
  AND t1.last_name = t2.last_name
  AND t1.postal_code = t2.postal_code
WHERE t1.id < t2.id
```

This is pretty standard, and I've done similar queries before. But I'm finding this query takes way too long to complete and return records (I haven't let it run to completion, but it takes over 10min). When I run an EXPLAIN on it, no key is used for t1 -- it's running a full table scan and the last_name index is used for t2.

I'm looking for tips/ideas to help improve performance and make the query reasonably functional.

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67507299/edit) to include the exact schema as well as the output of `EXPLAIN`.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this will speed up that query:

```
INDEX(first_name, last_name, postal_code, id, weight)
```

Comment: He already mentioned "The id column is a primary key and the other three columns have indexes"

Comment: @IndraKumarS - Not separate single-column indexes.  I want you to try a composite index with the columns in the order given.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not deleting the records -- I need to identify the potential
> duplicates and return them for further analysis.

So Try this out

```
SELECT

    GROUP_CONCAT(`id`) as entries,
    COUNT(*) c,
    CONCAT(
        `first_name`,
        "|",
        `last_name`,
        "|",
        `postal_code`
    ) AS title
FROM
    dupe_table
GROUP BY
    title
HAVING
    c > 1
```

The "entries" will have all entries -  First one is original Rest are dupes and c- how many duplicates